# Can't access favorite rooms from Meta Stack Exchange's chat

Tags: support, status-bydesign, chat, mobile-web

If I access chat from Meta Stack Exchange then tap on the "favorite" tab I just get a blank screen.[image]

This is not the case for Chemistry Stack Exchange or a couple of other daughter sites.

Comment: Meta has its own chat server not connected to the rest of the sites (same as Stack Overflow). You don't have any favorites here.

Comment: @animuson Why don’t you post this as an answer? Answer are indexed and better to find than comments. ;)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Support questions can't be dismissed as "by design". It's either a [tag:support] question on its own, or it's a [tag:status-bydesign] [tag:bug].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As animuson commented, Meta Stack Exchange has its own separate chat server (chat.meta.stackexchange.com), with its own separate chat rooms and overall system from most of the Stack Exchange network sites (chat.stackexchange.com).

The reason why you don't see your favorite rooms from other sites there is because you only see favorite rooms from the same chat server. As most sites share the same chat server, you see favorite sites by accessing chat from a different site because they're also hosted on chat.stackexchange.com.

As an aside, if you tried accessing chat from Stack Overflow, it also wouldn't work, because Stack Overflow also has its own separate chat server, chat.stackoverflow.com.